# Populating ListView by Images from the Pictures Library (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

So I am able to populate the ListView by images one at a time by using this syntax:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(await file.OpenReadAsync());
PhotoListView.Items.Add(bitmap);
```

However I want my ListView to display all the photos in a specific folder in the Pictures Library, for example the Camera Roll folder. Doing the same thing as the above, and adding codes that allows me to open the folder using the **StorageFolder** gives me an error:

```
failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Storage.StorageFile' to type 'ImageSource'
```

I think it has something to do with **List<>** but I do not know exactly how to use it. By the way, I may also consider using **FilePicker** as long as I can view all the images **within my application** and not in the Picture Library itself. It's because I've seen examples of it and what it does is placing the app in the background and open the library to show the images, which is no good for me.

So my question is, how do I exactly do it? and what are the codes behind it? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: A folder can contain any type of file: pdf, txt, doc, etc. You cannot convert a folder to a list of images; think about it, what if there is a txt file which cannot be converted into an image, what then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, it has to do something with Lists. So I researched quite a bit and then came up with this code:

```
StorageFolder appFolder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("appFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFolder temp = await appFolder.CreateFolderAsync("temp", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

List<StorageFile> FileList = (await temp.GetFilesAsync()).ToList();

List<string> ImageList = new List<string>();

    foreach (var imageFile in FileList)
        {
            ImageList.Add(imageFile.Path);
        }

this.PhotoListView.DataContext = ImageList;
```

The ListView also uses binding so the images in my appFolder will be added automatically in it.